# Corner spot where three faces meet

Tags: mirror

I tried modeling this with modifiers:

[image]

Ideally I want to create only the part on one side and have the other two added by modifiers.

How would you do this? I mirrored it 90 degrees once and then copied the original to the top. Can I apply two separate mirror modifiers on one object, so they don't apply on top of each other? That way I could mirror the original 90 degrees in Z and 90 degrees in Y direction without ending up with four objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make this with linked duplications that I would join later on, but you could do it with 2 *Mirror* modifiers:

- Create your shape. Put an empty on the axis.
- Give your shape a *Mirro*r modifier, choose the empty as *Mirror Object*.
- Rotate the empty 45° on the Z axis.
- Create a second empty (perhaps another shape) at the exact same place as the first one.
- Give your shape a second *Mirro*r modifier, choose the second empty as *Mirror Object*.
- Rotate the second empty 45° on the Y axis.
- You should be right.

[image]

Comment: Oh man, I tried that using only one empty for mirroring. Of course that couldn't work. Thank you!